# Pass parameter from jenkins stage to gradle task

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I have this jenkins stage where I am trying to pass a paramter to a gradle task. It seems like the gradle task does not recieve it

Jenkins

```
stage('Version Bump') {
    steps {
        script {
            version = (new Date().format('YYYY.ww.')) + env.BUILD_NUMBER
            sh './gradlew bumpVersion --no-daemon -Pversion=${version}'
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle task

```
task bumpVersion() {
    doFirst {
        println version
    }
}
```

The version isnt printed. I have confirmed the value is correct by echo-ing in the jenkins file.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use double quotes on the following line:

```
        sh "./gradlew bumpVersion --no-daemon -Pversion=${version}"
```

Otherwise Groovy doesn’t replace `${version}` and then the run shell finds the unset `version` *shell* variable and expands it to an empty string (which is then printed by Gradle – making it appear as if nothing was printed at all).